# Lagrange multipliers - hard one

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, supremum-and-infimum

Given set $D=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:x_1^2+44x_2^2\le5\}$ and function $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given us $f(x)=13x_1-22x_2$. I have to find  supremum  and infimum of $f$ and tell whether they are reached by $f$ in $D$ and in any interior point of D. When we focus only on $D'=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:x_1^2+44x_2^2=5\}$ we can use Lagrange multipliers but the original problem is much harder. How to solve this?

Comment: On the contrary: the interior problem is much easier, because $f$ is differentiable, so just look at the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

The theory of inequality-constrained optimization is very well-developed (particularly for convex problems such as yours). However you can solve your particular problem with the following elementary observation: every extremum of $f$ is either

1. on the active set $\partial D$ (which you say you know how to solve), or
2. on the interior of the feasible set.

Do you see why $f$ can't possibly have extrema on the interior of $D$?

---

Here's a bit more explanation. Suppose you are trying to solve

$$\min_x f(x)\quad \textrm{s.t.}\quad g(x) \geq 0.$$

A (local) solution to this optimization problem must be of one of the two following types:

1. A critical point of $f$ *inside* the feasible region, i.e.
   $$\nabla f = 0, \quad g > 0.$$
2. A point *on the boundary* of the feasible region, but where the function $f$ cannot decrease further without leaving the feasible region because its negative gradient points *straight out* of the feasible region. Since $\nabla g$ is perpendicular to level sets of $g$, a convenient way of encoding this condition -- that $f$'s gradient is perpendicular to the boundary -- is that $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ for some $\lambda \geq 0$. So in other words, the conditions for this case being true are that
   $$g = 0, \quad \nabla f = \lambda \nabla g, \quad \lambda \geq 0$$
   for some $\lambda.$

Finally notice that both conditions can be encoded simultaneously by the variational problem
$$\underset{x, \lambda}{\operatorname{ext}} f(x) - \lambda g(x) \quad \textrm{s.t.} \quad \lambda \geq 0,$$
and this is the extension of the method of Lagrange multipliers to inequality constraints. *However*, the variational problem merely encodes the same information as in the two cases analyzed above; and in your case it is very easy to treat these two cases directly. The method of Lagrange multipliers in the form I've written above is mostly useful for problems with very large numbers $m$ of constraints, where directly checking all $2^m$ possible active sets is intractable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see it.

Comment: @malex What are the critical points of a linear function?

Comment: Linear function  has no critical points, right?

Comment: @malex Some do, yours does not.  Suppose I give you a disk on a plane and I ask you to construct a linear function full of critical points inside the disk.  Can you do it?  Think geometrically.  After you do it, think: what is the difference between what you just did and the linear function you are given?  Hint: some lines have zero slope.  Some don't.